# CSS align two text sections center (horizontally)

Tags: html, css

The Image shows what the problem is, I have written the media query for this part of the width (mobile versions) but can't seem to align my two section texts properly on center below image .

Image - [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCzEz.jpg

Comment: share your code

Comment: https://codepad.co/snippet/MnxuSXBT#_=_

Comment: Check answer may be it will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to set two column(50% width) for two text section or min width then you are able to center horizontally.

```
.right {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;

}
.left {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}


<div class="right">
  <p>This text is centered.</p>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <p>This text is centered.</p>
</div>
```

---- In Bootstrap ----

```
  <style>
  .text1{
  text-align: center;
  }
  </style>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <div class="text1">
    left side data.
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
    <div class="text1">
    left side data.
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrXcl.png)

Comment: Can you be any more specific on how to do that?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/88Iv4 

It didn't help

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then it will be easy. I will post answer in bootstrap

Comment: Sorry but I'm not , I just downloaded the text editor 2 days ago (thats when I finished the basic HTML/CSS course online) and wanted to see If I could make a test web-page . It seems like I'm not .

Comment: The first answer which I posted in html it will work, I was tried it then i posted that answer.

Comment: Then, It seems like I have some unnesesary margins or padding or some attributes , ok thanks mate, I'll try to find it

Comment: If you satisfied with this answer, please mark this answer accepted.

Comment: Sure , if no one else will come up with better answer

Answer (score 1):

Test with a class in css:

`.myClass{
    text-align: center;
}`

Or with the HTML center tag.

Comment: Yeah I've set the left and right sections with Class attributes to text-align:center but it didnt help, also I dont think that HTML's center tag will be good here , because I want to align this texts on center only for mobile versions

Answer (score 0):

In your media query you have set a width i think.. So what you do to make them center just add margin auto..

```
.box{
    display:block;
    width:250px;
    float: none;
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }
```

so it will be aligned center..